# How do I only plot histogram for only certain columns of a data-frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the data that I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwuSA.png)

Let say I have the data-frame in a variable called df, if I do df.hist(), it will show one histogram for each category in the data-frame, but I only want one histogram for each category from category 1 to 5. How do I do that?

Comment: You pass it the `column` parameter when you call `.hist()`

Comment: @G.Anderson You are right, appreciate the help.

Comment: Happy to help! But always remember to check the documentation before anything else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution:

```
df.hist(column=["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5"])
```